# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am new to react native and react navigation and I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')

I don't understand my because I am just using the same code which already worked, but now it's not working.

I am trying to make a back arrow that send you back to the MachineList screen.

```
//doesn't work
const AddMachineDetails = ({route}, props) => {

...

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("MachinesList")}>
        <BackArrow />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

So when I press my backarrow it send me this error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')`

Here is my Navigation file:

```
import MachinesList from '../components/MachinesList'
import AddMachineDetails from '../components/AddMachineDetails';

...

function MachineListStackScreen() {
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
            <Stack.Screen name='MachinesList' component={MachinesList}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='AddMachineDetails' component={AddMachineDetails}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

...
```

I think the problem is somewhere in this code, but if not, I'll show you more of my code

Here is an example where my `navigation.navigate` work perfectly:

```
//no specific imports  (but works)

const MachinesList = (props) => {

...


<TouchableOpacity style={styles.machineBox} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('AddMachineDetails', {item})}>
```

Comment: Here: `const AddMachineDetails = ({route}, props) =>` it seems to don't get the good "props" becuase the props.navigation is undefined

Comment: do you have an idea of what should I do ? because I am just doing as usual (I've checked if there was any typing mistake) but this time it dosen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *desctruct* the props argument.

```
const AddMachineDetails = ({route, ...props}) => { ... }
```

or

```
const AddMachineDetails = ({route, navigation, ...props}) => { ... }  // then straightly use the *navigation*
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here `({route}, props) =>`.

You are destructuring the first argument, but there aren't other parameters passed and that's why "props" variable is undefined.

You have two solutions:

1. Just use props:

```js
const AddMachineDetails = (props) => {
```

2. Destructure props:

```js
const AddMachineDetails = ({route, navigation, ...props}) => {
...

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MachinesListDetails")}>
       <BackArrow />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: what about the rest of the props? :))

Comment: Other props don't have anything to do with the question

Comment: the OP might blindly use your snippet, then start wondering *why is **props** undefined?*. Just edit the question ;) All you have to do is add a `...props`